# Use triple integrals to integrate over a tetrahedron

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Integrate $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 - z$ over the tetrahedron with vertices $(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 3)$.

I need to use triple integrals to solve this, so I made a diagram and set the $x$ as: $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $y$ as: $0 \leq y \leq x$ (because two of the points form the $y = x$ line on the $xy$ plane).

For the $z$ bounds, I took the last three points and got two vectors: $(-1, 0, 0)$ and $(-1, -1, 3)$. I took the cross product and got: $(0, 3, 1)$ to get the plane $z = 3 - 3y$. So the $z$ bounds are from $0$ to $3 - 3y$.

Is the way I formed this integral correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section on the $z=0$ plane is a triangle made of points for which $y\geq x$ (you took the inequality reversed) and $x,y\in[0,1]$. The section with the plane $z=z_0$ is a triangle having its vertices in $(0,0,z_0),(0,1-z_0/3,z_0),(1-z_0/3,1-z_0/3,z_0)$, hence you can write your integral in the following form:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}I&=&\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{1-z/3}\int_{0}^{y}(x^2+y^2-z)\,dx\,dy\,dz = \int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{1-z/3}\left(\frac{4}{3}y^3-zy\right)\,dy\,dz\\&=&\int_{0}^{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{17z}{18}+\frac{5z^2}{9}-\frac{17z^3}{162}+\frac{z^4}{243}\right)\,dz=-\frac{7}{40}.\end{eqnarray*}$$