# Limits of triple integral over tetrahedron

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the tetrahedron with vertices $(0,0,0),(0,2,0),(-4,2,0),(0,2,4)$.

To figure the limits for integration in $x,y,z$ I followed this logic

The base of the tetrahedron can be thought of as being in the $xy$ plane, so
we get

$$-4<x<0$$ and $$-x/2<y<2$$.

To find the bounds for $z$ it is more complicated because I need to find the 3 planes where the 3 faces above the $xy$ plane lie.

How do I get the bounds for $z$ from those 3 plane equations?

Comment: check out this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878003/use-triple-integrals-to-integrate-over-a-tetrahedron?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the cross product of two vectors lying on the surface of the plane to find a normal vector of the plane. This would give you the equation of the plane. In particular, $(0, 2, 4) - (-4, 2, 0) = (4, 0, 4)$, so $(4, 0, 4) \times (0, 2, 4) = (-8, -16, 8)$. Then, an equation for your plane would be $-x - 2y + z = 0 \implies z = x + 2y$.

So your integral would be
$$
\int_{-4}^0\int_{-x/2}^2\int_0^{x + 2y}f(x, y, z)\,dz\,dy\,dx.
$$